# PySpark createOrReplaceGlobalTempView with db

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a temporary view in pyspark with the db attached to it.

```
.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(f"{db}.{table}")
```

However I get the error

```
2023-11-01 19:17:52 Create View: db.table
2023-11-01 19:17:55   File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1034, in sql
2023-11-01 19:17:55   File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
2023-11-01 19:17:55   File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
2023-11-01 19:17:55   File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
2023-11-01 19:17:55   File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
2023-11-01 19:17:55 pyspark.sql.utilspyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: db.table; line 1 pos 137;
```

If I remove the {db} part in both creating the view and reading I can access it. Is there any way to use it with the db part.

This is where I create the views.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from util.constants import valid_data_sources, get_database_for_source, all_table_names


def create_views(config):
    spark = create_and_return_spark_session()
    for source in valid_data_sources():
        db = get_database_for_source(source, config)
        if db == "":
            continue
        for table in all_table_names():
            print(f"Create View: {db}.{table}")
            spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(f"/csv/{db}.{table}.csv").createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(f"{db}.{table}")
    return spark

def create_and_return_spark_session():
    if SparkSession.getActiveSession() == None:
        print('NO ACTIVE')
        return SparkSession.builder.appName('Local Spark Session1').getOrCreate()
    else:
        print('ACTIVE')
        return SparkSession.getActiveSession()
```

Here I read the data

```
class LocalSparkDataConnectorTest:
    def __init__(self, config: Configuration):
        self.config: Configuration = config
        self.spark = create_views(config)

    def read_view(self):
        df = self.spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db.table")
```

Also I want to ask if the usage of create_and_return_spark_session is correct?

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

> `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` views are tied to a system preserved temporary database `global_temp`.

[<sup>Source</sup>](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html#parameters)

As such, you won't be able to tie any `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` view to a specific database, since it's necessarily married to the `global_temp` database.

If you need your temporary view to be tied to a specific database, you can alternatively create [a *non-global* temporary view](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView.html):

```
my_dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView(f"{db}.{table}")
```

Comment: I still get an error this way

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü It would be helpful if you'd provide more information about the error you're referencing (including the full stack trace), along with a [mre] of the code that causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, global temporary views aren't linked to a database. They are cross-session and stored in a system database named `global_temp`.

You can't actually specify a custom database name when creating a global temp view, *however* you can access it using the `global_temp` database name.

[You can see how it works in the docs here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView).

To create a global temporary view and access it:

```py
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("table_name")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.table_name").show()
```

If you really need it to be a non-temporary view, you can specify the database like so:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("db_name.table_name")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name").show()
```